# Iterating over a HashMap and putting values into a List

Tags: java

I have a HashMap which contains various "Product" as keys and "Product Group ID" as values. 
I need to seperate out products which have the same group IDs and put them in a new ArrayList (of only products i.e. the keys).
I'm stuck as to how I can do this, any help would be appreciated!

Something like this:
HashMap: (1,a) (2,b) (3,c) (4,a) (5,b)
New ArrayList should contain: {1,4} - this list gets sent to another function to get processed.
Again 2,5 should be stored in another list and get processed.
Finally 3 should get stored in an array list and go for processing.

Comment: Create a Map<ProductGroupId, List<Product>>. Then iterate on the entries of your original map, and populate this new map.

Comment: @adityaaraop99, change the title if you are expecting answer as Basil Sir said.

Comment: Your example data should be rewritten as pairs, as is conventional for discussing a map.

Comment: Rewrote the question as you guys said. I don't have much experience with stack overflow so please excuse if I wasn't clear with the question.

Comment: @BasilBourque, any chance you could give me a solution to this?

Comment: So the key `Product` is an Integer, and the value `ProductGroupId` is a String for the sake of this example? More concrete data example might help.

Answer (score 2):

One way that you could do it is to have another `HashMap` of `ArrayLists` and then add values to it. You can try the following code:

I'm assuming that Product is a String and that the ID is an Integer, but you can change it.

```
Map < Integer, String > sourceMap = Map.of ( 1 , "a" , 2 , "b" , 3 , "c" , 4 , "a " , 5 , "b" );

HashMap <String, ArrayList<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry <Integer, String> entry : sourceMap.entrySet()) {
    String value = entry.getValue();
    int key = entry.getKey();

    if (result.containsKey(value)) {
        ArrayList<Integer>temp = result.get(value);
        temp.add(key);
    } else {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(key);
        result.put(value, temp);
    }
}
System.out.println ("result.toString():\n" + result);
```

Now, you have a `HashMap` called `result` that contains the `ArrayList` that you wanted. You can iterate through to get each individual `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @BasilBourque. I was writing the code in StackOverflow so I didn't have any autocomplete suggestions but instead of `result.contains()`, it should be `result.containsKey()`. A small mistake, but I have fixed the code.

Comment: This seems to work now, as seen [here](https://www.codiva.io/p/a00d5e6d-ba88-423f-9059-29d33d2a4f5f). But I've not thought through the correctness for sure (the example data in the Question is confusing). Good enough to get my up-vote.

Comment: Grouping with a collector is much cleaner in my opinion. ;)

Comment: True. This was just the first solution that came to my mind.

Comment: @Michael There is value in showing the more "manual" approach too. Using lambdas and collectors is a bit magical for newbies.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following pattern.

Let's assume you have a simple `HashMap<String, String>`. Then you can just do this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
   Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue(), 
   Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.toList()))
)
```

And the result is: `{a=[1, 4], b=[2, 5], c=[3]}`

The lists can simply be accessed by `result.get("a")` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
private static Map<Product, Long> map = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fillTestData();
    List<Product> products = findProductByGroup(1L);
    System.out.println(products.size());
}

private static List<Product> findProductByGroup(Long groupId){
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == groupId)
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static void fillTestData() {
    String product = "product";
    long groupId = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            groupId = 1;
        }else {
            groupId = 2;
        }
        map.put(new Product(product+i), groupId);
    }
}
```

otherwhise you have declare clearly what you need